python tree diagram displaying several smaller diagrams instead of 1
The tree produces is split into several smaller ones, how would I get it to produce one big one instead? current output
{
"129": {
        "rank": "CPT",
        "ct_name": "Dymphna",
        "NIC": ""
},..
}

this is a extract of the json file
If the NIC is None or "" then they are the root node and the nodes connecting to them should have the previous node name as their NIC. The key has no significance and is just a record number, and the entritd in the json file are in no particular order
import json
from graphviz import Digraph


with open("members.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


dot = Digraph()


all_members = set()
for member_id, member_data in data.items():
    dot.node(str(member_id), member_data["ct_name"])
    all_members.add(member_id)
    if "NIC" in member_data:
        all_members.add(member_data["NIC"])


for member_id, member_data in data.items():
    if member_id!= "0" and "NIC" in member_data and member_data["NIC"]:
        dot.edge(str(member_data["NIC"]), str(member_id))


dot.render("chain_of_command", format="png", cleanup=True)

got rather lost and could only get the root node to display for the other attempts

it seems you have to use some variable to keep previous node name and later put it in NIC.
